# How to install an aix71 client using NIM on Linux (NIMOL)

Tags: linux, aix

I want to install aix71 client using nimol,i read [somewhere](http://www.aixmind.com/?p=1162) only 5.3
clients were supported

But i found this on aix71 cd,is possible to install aix 7.1 with nimol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't  working maybe someone want to investigate,i have tried this  simple howto wrote by me for start
thanks to this [links](http://www.aixmind.com/?p=1162) for clear explanation
The procedure start but give me error
BA010005 if use firewall
Without firewall tftp transfer works fine
but after "disk search" give error 0c52 and
stuck at 12%
SElinux was disabled

This is my dirty and fast howto

```
#require
centos6,(centos7 is a lot of pain because switched from sysv init to systemd)
dhcpd server
tftp server 
fqdn hostname must resolve via /etc/hosts or dns
firewall: if use open  67:69 tcp e udp,514 udp(rsyslog)

#install those packages
epel-release    
libc-i386
tftp-server
tftp
rcpbind     #link /etc/rc.d/init.d/rpcbin to  /etc/rc.d/init.d/portmap
perl-xml    
dhcpd  server
nfs-utils
xinetd
perl-XML-LibXML
bind-utils
ssh

#install those rpms from aix dvd 71 dvd-1
for i in   nimol-1.0-4.noarch.rpm  osinstall-1.0-1.noarch.rpm;
do rpm -Uvh $i;done

#configure nimol
touch /etc/nimol.conf
nimol_config -m /usr/bin/ssh -C #configure nimol

#example nimol.conf
NIMOL_SERVER youserver.fqdn
PORTMAP_STARTED yes
REMOTE_ACCESS_METHOD /usr/bin/ssh
NIMOL_SUBNET 192.168.0.0
LABEL default /export/aix/default
NIMOL_SYSLOG_FACILITY local2

#run nimol
#insert dvd aix71 in /dev/cdrom
nimol_config


#edit dchpd.conf and enable boot
#boot
allow bootp;
use-host-decl-names on;

#check if nfs working
exportfs -v

#enable syslog remote(not required)
syslogd     #run with options -r -h
rsyslogd    #edit /etc/rsyslogd enable 514 udp remote

#create first client
nimol_install -c aix1 -g 192.168.0.203 -m 00:*:*:*:*:* -s 255.255.255.0 -L default
service dchpd restart

#if give error check tftp and dhcp conf files
#you can check if working with 
tftp yourserver
get /tftpboot/aix1

#to run client
#boot from aix(sms menu selected from asmi or serial console)
##configura ipl
#boot from network

#last warning: if softlink of tftp doesn't work use cp or hard link
ln default.chrp.mp.ent aix1
```

Comment: Connection seems estabilished but tftp transfer fail

Comment: Firewall disabled and works,probably firewall configuration need to be revisioned

Comment: Doesn't work,error 0c52 after "disk search"

Comment: NIMOL is actually a pretty ugly hack, but AIX 7.1 install is possible, this is how the HMC does it, too. In SMS, were you able to ping the NIM? and what IPL settings did you configure? For the 0c52 error, that's a pivotroot error - this could mean your installation ressource is damaged. What did you boot, an mksysb?

And you could try to enable debug output via `911` as described in [Enabling Debug Output While Installing/Restoring](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1011829#6)